# How do I use SSI for a local site on my computer?

Tags: apache, xampp, ssi, server-side-includes

Ok, so noob here. I'm in a class where they briefly mentioned SSIs without going into any real detail on how to get it to work on a local computer (without uploading files to the server, etc). Now I'm supposed to be using it in my assignments, but I can't find a way to preview it.

So, can someone please explain how I can get SSI to function on my computer? I have XAMPP with Apache installed, but I have no idea how to use it (we haven't gotten to that part of the course yet). If anyone has a noob way of explaining how it works and how to get the Server Side Includes to show up for me, that would be very helpful. I stumbled across [this site](http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/51) but it wasn't much help. Thank you!

Comment: the site you mention is for IIS with SSI, as you are using xampp
probably this will help http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html, I use SSI only with nginx, and it's variant ESI with Varnish.. but the concept is the same, enable SSI with 'Option +includes' and 'XBitHack on' on your (Apache2|httpd|foo|yoursiteconfig).conf, and enjoy

Comment: How do I enable SSI though on Apache? Can you provide more instruction, as I'm really not familiar with the interface at all. How do I get to this conf file, and what do I do when I get to it?

Comment: I don't use windows.. but 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\conf\httpd.conf', the basic strucure normaly have a 'conf.d' and/or a 'sites-enabled' on the Apache..dation dir, use a this example config http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#page-header. in virtualhost DocumentRoot put your site path on O.S.
and in this virtualhost put the 'XBitHack on'

Comment: sorry my poor english